# How to load Flink Streaming data from Zeppelin

Tags: scala, apache-flink, apache-zeppelin, flink-streaming

I'm starting to use Flink on Zeppelin and trying to run the simplest program in streaming: *wordcount*.
When I run this code in local mode using the terminal, it works.

Here is how I do it: https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.2/quickstart/setup_quickstart.html

This is the code:

```
object SocketWindowWordCount {

  /** Main program method */
  def main(args: Array[String]) : Unit = {

    // the host and the port to connect to
    var hostname: String = "localhost"
    var port: Int = 0

    try {
      val params = ParameterTool.fromArgs(args)
      hostname = if (params.has("hostname")) params.get("hostname") else "localhost"va
      port = params.getInt("port")
    } catch {
      case e: Exception => {
        System.err.println("No port specified. Please run 'SocketWindowWordCount " +
          "--hostname <hostname> --port <port>', where hostname (localhost by default) and port " +
          "is the address of the text server")
        System.err.println("To start a simple text server, run 'netcat -l <port>' " +
          "and type the input text into the command line")
        return
      }
    }

    // get the execution environment
    val env: StreamExecutionEnvironment = StreamExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment

    // get input data by connecting to the socket
    val text = env.socketTextStream(hostname, port, '\n')

    // parse the data, group it, window it, and aggregate the counts 
    val windowCounts = text
          .flatMap { w => w.split("\\s") }
          .map { w => WordWithCount(w, 1) }
          .keyBy("word")
          .timeWindow(Time.seconds(5))
          .sum("count")

    // print the results with a single thread, rather than in parallel
    windowCounts.print().setParallelism(1)

    env.execute("Socket Window WordCount")
  }

  /** Data type for words with count */
  case class WordWithCount(word: String, count: Long)
}
```

However, when I try to run this code on Zeppelin... I do not how to do it.
I guess I need to open a socket in terminal too but I do not how make that Flink connect with this port. Should I open several windows on Flink?

I can **summary** the question in: **how to load flink streaming data from Zeppelin???**

I need add some Scala method at the end like:

```
import scala.io.Source

val programRunning = Source.from"Socket"...?
```

Thanks in advance for your help! :)

Comment: Hi, I am not a flink user, so not sure how to use flink streaming exactly, but this might be helpful to you. [Flink Streaming using Zeppelin, 2016.09](https://rawkintrevo.org/2016/09/30/big-data-for-n00bs-my-first-streaming-flink-program-twitter/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a terminal, you can use

```
nc -lk 9999
```

to establish a service bound to port 9999 that will send whatever it receives on stdin to its clients.

[Apache Zeppelin: A friendlier way to Flink](http://2016.flink-forward.org/kb_sessions/apache-zeppelin-a-friendlier-way-to-flink/) might also be helpful.

Comment: **Thanks so much** The documentation was very useful and solved my problem!