# What is the best way to visualize Flink Streaming data in Zeppelin in case of the amount of data is large

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming, apache-zeppelin

What is the best way to visualize Flink Streaming data in Zeppelin in case of the amount of data is large

Is this approach in the following link is the best one?, how it works:
https://github.com/TU-Berlin-DIMA/i2

Or I can use this answer:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/44265198/8972051

Answer (score 1):

For an up-to-date guide to using Flink with Zeppelin, see this series of blog posts:

1. https://medium.com/@zjffdu/flink-on-zeppelin-part-1-get-started-2591aaa6aa47
2. https://medium.com/@zjffdu/flink-on-zeppelin-part-2-batch-711731df5ad9
3. https://medium.com/@zjffdu/flink-on-zeppelin-part-3-streaming-5fca1e16754
4. https://medium.com/@zjffdu/flink-on-zeppelin-part-4-advanced-usage-998b74908cd9